# Want to Create Trigger with Insert and Delete Functionlity

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create Trigger in which row is inserted to another table and then delete that row from the table from which row has been fetched.

Code I have tried for that purpose but not running successfully.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `testdatabase`$$
DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trig_test`$$
CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `trig_test` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_test` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE param4,param5 VARCHAR(50);
    SELECT reg_info INTO param4 FROM PRICEIES WHERE MSISDN=NEW.MOBILE;
    SELECT platform INTO param5 FROM PRICEIES WHERE MSISDN=NEW.MOBILE;    
    INSERT INTO `tbl_replica`(`param1`,`param2`,`param3`,`param4`,`param5`) 
VALUES(new.`param1`,new.`param2`,new.`param3`,param4,param5);
        DELETE FROM tbl_test WHERE id=NEW.id;   
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

How can i will implement above code for mentioned purpose?

Comment: have you tried the trigger ? does it returns a error when you run it ? if yes what is the error?

Comment: If your trigger is first copying the new row to a different table and then deletes that row from the original table, why would you insert at all?

If you use a BEFORE insert on trigger, you can directly insert into the repolica table. Assuming that there's a reason you don't want to insert into the replica table directly...